# SequelizeDatabaseError - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with mysql as database.

After I add the entity relationship for two tables, below error shows:

```
error: Unhandled Rejection at: Promise 
{"name":"SequelizeDatabaseError","parent":{"code":"ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN","errno":1215,"sqlState":"HY000",
"sqlMessage":"Cannot add foreign key constraint",
"sql":"ALTER TABLE `quizzes_option` ADD `quizzesOptionListId` 
CHAR(36) BINARY, ADD CONSTRAINT `quizzes_option_quizzesOptionListId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`quizzesOptionListId`) REFERENCES `quizzes_option_list` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;"},"original":{"code":"ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN","errno":1215,"sqlState":"HY000","sqlMessage":"Cannot add foreign key constraint","sql":"ALTER TABLE `quizzes_option` ADD `quizzesOptionListId` CHAR(36) BINARY, ADD CONSTRAINT `quizzes_option_quizzesOptionListId_foreign_idx` 
FOREIGN KEY (`quizzesOptionListId`) REFERENCES `quizzes_option_list` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;"},"sql":"ALTER TABLE `quizzes_option` ADD `quizzesOptionListId` CHAR(36) BINARY, ADD CONSTRAINT `quizzes_option_quizzesOptionListId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`quizzesOptionListId`) REFERENCES `quizzes_option_list` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;"}
```

quizzes_option_model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const option = sequelizeClient.define('quizzes_option', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    score: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  option.associate = function (models) {
    option.belongsTo(models.quizzes_option_list);
  };

  return option;
};
```

option-list.model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const optionList = sequelizeClient.define('quizzes_option_list', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    }
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  optionList.associate = function (models) {
    optionList.hasMany(models.quizzes_option);
  };

  return optionList;
};
```